# Ruby using two gems that require different version of another gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using activerecord and feedzirra(RSS parsing library). activerecord needs activesupport v3.2.8 and feedzirra needs v3.1.1. When I use both of them at the same time, I get error that they are conflicting because both of them require different versions of activesupport (3.2.8 vs 3.1.1.

What are my options?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the latest feedzirra, it doesn't depend on 3.1.1 afaik:

```
gem 'feedzirra', :git => 'https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra.git'
```

Comment: I used rvm gem install feedzirra. Does this not install the latest version?

Comment: That installs the latest released version.

Comment: Ok, well that installed 0.1.3. Looking here: http://rubygems.org/gems/feedzirra , it shows it depends on activesupport 3.1.1 - Looking at activerecord, it shows dependency as 3.2.8

Comment: The easiest way for your project is to use bundler (add a Gemfile), and specify the feedzirra as I suggested. It will use the latest (still unreleased) version.